# Trigger KeyDown event in older browsers with JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, cross-browser

```
    export const triggerKey = (k) => {
  let key = '';
  let keyCode = 0;
  if (k === 'down') {
    key = 'ArrowDown';
    keyCode = 40;
  } else if (k === 'up') {
    key = 'ArrowUp';
    keyCode = 38;
  } else if (k === 'right') {
    key = 'ArrowRight';
    keyCode = 39;
  } else if (k === 'left') {
    key = 'ArrowLeft';
    keyCode = 37;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
  window.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key, keyCode,
  }));

  return null;
};
```

This function is supposed to trigger a keydown event and it works fine on chrome latest versions. But this is not supported by chrome older version. How to trigger the same functionality on older browsers?